# Find border vertices of graph

Tags: matlab, graph

What's a good way to find border vertices of a graph?

```
Vu = [6.6275    1.3984    0.4537;
6.6420    1.4686    0.6121;
6.6444    1.3235    0.4482;
6.6646    1.2665    0.4616;
6.6725    1.3758    0.5064;
6.6800    1.3213    0.4924;
6.6807    1.2857    0.4838;
6.6893    1.3539    0.5141;
6.7136    1.4189    0.6150;
6.7518    1.3673    0.6039;
6.7685    1.2392    0.5562];

edgeList = [1,3;3,9;2,9;1,2;8,10;7,8;7,11;10,11;3,6;3,4;4,7;6,7;3,5;6,8;5,8;9,10;5,9];
G = graph(edgeList(:,1), edgeList(:,2)); 
figure(1);
plot(G, 'XData',Vu(:,1),'YData', Vu(:,2), 'ZData',Vu(:,3));
K = unique(convhulln(Vu)); % K=[1 2 3 4 9 10 11]
```

`convhulln` is missing one border vertex, not sure why. The border vertices I'm expecting should be `[1 2 9 10 11 7 4 3]`.

The image is:

[image]

Comment: Variable `Vu` is not defined, please edit to have a minimal, reproducible example. Also check the definition of convex hull, which is very different from "border" vertex. Vertices of convex hull are on the border, but the reverse is not true to keep the hull convex (without "hollow").

Comment: Added Vu example.